# XNA project unit testing, builds but errors running tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I'm trying to set up some unit tests for an XNA project. After some ordeals with making sure the test project was set to build in the configuration manager and removing references to the XNA content project, I finally got the tests to build.

But the tests still won't run half of the time. If I click "run selection" from the test view I continually get the error "No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))." If I instead press the "run all tests in solution" button, it sometimes runs, but usually it gives me this error: "Specific Cast is not Valid." if run all tests does work the first time (this seems to happen after updating from SVN), it stops working immediately after that.

I've found some people with similar issues:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/602985/unit-testing-does-not-work-with-xna-4-0

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/175cb376-9846-40fa-9197-50595cd32200/

But both seemed to have died without resolutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to post some code? Maybe even a zip of the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default XNA solution is not COM-Visible. The test framework seems to behave slightly better if it is COM-Visible. The easiest fix is to open AssemblyInfo.cs, find the line

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

And change false to true.

A [blog post by Carlos Quintero](http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2008/09/29/the-strange-case-of-quot-no-such-interface-supported-quot-error-80004002-loading-an-add-in.aspx) led me to the fix. This only works about half of the time, and I'm not actually certain it's responsible for fixing the problem.

Aaron Stebner claims in a [forum post](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63814/392754.aspx#392754) that it shouldn't work whatsoever if the test project references a ContentProject, and references the WPDT release notes which agree with that. In my tests just now, the Game project itself must not reference a ContentProject for the tests to run succesfully every time. I've taken to removing the reference to run tests and replacing it afterwards. Depending on your test coverage this can work well or be useless, but it looks like it's the best we can get with the built-in test suite.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of annoying, but if you right-click the test project and choose `Debug->Start New Instance`, it should build it and then run the tests. The annoying thing is that since you're debugging, any failed asserts pause execution. You may want this, however, so it's not *that* big of a deal.

Comment: Yeah,that's what we've had to do for the past few weeks. There are far worse fates, but one thing that makes it worse is that the ExpectedException doesn't really feel like working either (I don't recall why at the moment). So instead I have to catch the exception in the test and it breaks on every single test like this.

Comment: @AJD - There are some notes on [ExpectedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) behaviours in the Remarks section of the docs. Perhaps they'd shed some light on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it's possible to isolate the target code in an ordinary .net class library project, and reference only that class library from the test project. This way, the usual testing features work just fine, since you don't reference an XNA project.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: @AJD - I think he means if your code doesn't require the use of XNA classes or, for example, if you were to break out a `Vector2` into two floats. But then, you're not really testing the exact same code which could introduce more errors and may *miss* other errors.

Comment: As Richard explained, if it is possible to move the code you want to test into a separate non-XNA assembly, then it would be possible to have your test code not reference XNA. This is what I did for the code I'm working on. My core functions are in library A, my tests are in ATest which references A, and my 'game' is in assembly B, which only references A. Then the ATest just works fine with the usual testing tools.